# How to halt provisioning of one VM until another VM is done?

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, chef-infra

Using Vagrant+Chef Solo I'm setting up two VMs: #1 is a TeamCity server, #2 is a TeamCity agent. Provisioning is done by first installing the TeamCity server package on VM #1, then the agent VM is booted and requests data from the server which is used to install the agent. That whole thing works fine.

But now I want to alter the server **after the agent is done provisioning**. I want to modify the server's database directly, to change an attribute that is only available after the agent has spun up. But is there a way for one VM's provisioning to trigger another VM? Once the agent is done I'd like to somehow resume provisioning the server, so I can make the database edit..

Any thoughts, recommendations, or feedback welcomed. I'm new to Vagrant, Chef, *and* TeamCity, so there's a chance I'm missing a much easier solution.

* *Why do I want to edit the DB directly you may be wondering? TeamCity agents must be authorized before they can be used, and I want to do this programmatically. The solution I've found is to directly edit the DB, because authorization functionality is not exposed via the TeamCity REST API (as far as I can tell)*

Answer (score 1):

If you can test the agent is installed/answering, you may add a ruby block looping over this test before continuing the recipe execution.

This loop should have a sleep and a counter to avoid infinite loops.

I've no knowledge of teamcity, so can't tell if it's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Chef is designed to manage your system, not simply provision it (though this is less true in the modern Cloud world with "golden image" strategies).  Nonetheless, in your case, you best bet is to just setup chef-client as a service that runs every 15 minutes.  Once the client has finished provisioning, the next run of the server will be able to authorize it.

If you really want to "trigger" the one from the other, you'd need either do that externally with something like etcd or consul, or you would need to setup an ssh keypair between the boxes and add a `ruby_block` on the client that either does the database modification directly, or calls `chef-client` on the server.